# C++ : get inherited type from abstract pointer vector

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, vector

So i have a vector that holds pointers of a Component abstract class 
 , and let's say i have 2 inherited classes from component , foo and bar , is there any way to get the pointer with type "foo" from this vector?

```
    vector<Component*> components;
    class foo : Component;
    class bar : Component;
    components.push_back(new foo());
    components.push_back(new bar());
```

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like bad design, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Each component does a completely different job than the other , they have almost nothing in common... The holder class loops through all the components and call all their virtual methods. that's the best way i can think of

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but usually, class-dependent behavior should be implemented as virtual functions (**polymorphism**). If you want that mechanism to be extendable (in the sense of adding new functions / operations over time without touchnig the concrete components), consider the **visitor** pattern.

Comment: I am not really going to extend it , the Component class has a Start ,an Update and a Render virtual function , nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep:

```
Component* c = components[0];
if (foo* f = dynamic_cast<foo*>(c)) {
    // use f
}
else {
    // c is not a foo. Maybe it's a bar, or something else
}
```

So if you want to write a function to *find* the `foo*`, you could do this (assuming C++11):

```
foo* find_foo(const std::vector<Component*>& components)
{
    for (auto c : components) {
        if (foo* f = dynamic_cast<foo*>(c)) {
            return f;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

The cast, `dynamic_cast<foo*>` will either return a valid `foo*` or `nullptr`, it **will not** throw. From the standard §5.2.7.9:

> The value of a failed cast to pointer type is the null pointer value of the required result type.

Comment: Will this work eventhougth the class doesn't contain virtual?

Comment: @user3562972 no, they have to be virtual. If it's not, the cast just won't compile, since the source type has to be polymorphic.

Comment: @dau_sama No, it will not throw.

Comment: @dau_sama You don't mean virtual interitance. You mean a virtual function (usually at least the destructor should be virtual).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by employing concepts of RTTI:-

```
#include <typeinfo>
//Using for loop iterate through all elements
if ( typeid(*iter) == typeid(Foo) )
  //You got the Foo object
```

But that's almost never preferable in C++.